# Web site/app that tracks movement and maps it on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to build a website to track my run distance, (have this working) while also tracking the path I take (like google maps when getting directions).

I'm not worried about storing it in a database yet, but if this is required to get the movement to be tracked on a map then I will.

I've looked at Google and see they have asset tracking, also Runtastic (but this doesn't appear to have an API). Also checked pubnub (but it doesn't seem to map the track)

I'm wanting to do it with HTML5 so that it runs in a browser. Has anyone managed to get this working and could share a guide on how to do it? (spent hours looking)

Answer (score 0):

[OwnTracks](http://owntracks.org/) might do the job as backend for storing and managing your recorded tracks.

Comment: Thankyou, but that is a native API. I want it to run in a web browser.